# UWP: Map control ZoomFinished event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, uwp-maps

I need to execute some code when the user finishes to zoom in/out the map. Its `ZoomLevelChanged` event is raised as the user zooms in or out, so it is not a solution for me (mainly because the code i want to execute is a pretty expensive operation). Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe set a timer when the user *starts* zooming, and if the event is called again, reset the timer. After the timer reaches say, 3 seconds, you can assume that they have finished zooming.

Comment: @MikeEason not the cleanes way i can think of but, i think it might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the performance is the main issue here, you can "rerender" your map elements only when the zoom level changes from one integer to another (1->2, 2->3 and so on) (skiping the part after coma). As far as I know the maximum value for `ZoomLevel` is 20 (for `2D`) mode. So I think it must be smooth enough for the user not to notice.

Some code:

```
public int ZoomLevel {get; set;} = initialZoomLevel;

private void OnZoomLevelChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if((int)Map.ZoomLevel!=ZoomLevel)
    {
        //Rerender stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I actualy already did this. and you are right. It is smooth enough for user not to notice

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better solution is to listen to the [LoadingStatusChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn637028) event, then take action when you get back [MapLoadingStatus.Loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.maploadingstatus).

```
public void LoadingStatusChangedEventHandler(MapControl sender, Object o)
{
    if (sender.LoadingStatus == MapLoadingStatus.Loaded)
    {
        // The map has stopped moving and finished rendering
        // If necessary, check that zoom level is different
        DoExpensiveOperation();
    }
}
```

I know the documentation for that event isn't great, but there's a little more information at [this code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps#handle-user-interaction-and-changes), and you may be able to find even more on the [git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl).

Good luck!!

Comment: nice idea, let me try